# Error while playing You tube Live Stream

Tags: android, youtube, live-streaming

I am trying to play You Tube Live stream through an Android app. Here is the code I used to play Live stream,

```
 btnvideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/myjoyonlinetube")));
            Log.i("Video", "Video Playing....");

            }
        });
```

But when I run the application, it loads You tube Mobile theme but when I press the play button of the stream, it gives "Live event playback is not supported on this client". I tried lot of times by changing the code, but it didn't work.

I am using Android 2.3.3 app, Galaxy Y smart phone.

Please help me to play that live stream.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited : Above code works well to play normal You tube videos. But it only didn't work for Live streams like above live stream in the URl.**

Comment: It means the you tube app does not support live event play on mobile app.. I don't think much can be done about that.. check out following thread for more info.. may be your carrier is blocking the live stream... https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/youtube/NLR4Z8yAhRU

Comment: @PrafulBhatnagar: Thanks for the reply. Is that means there is no way to view you tube live streaming through an Android app? Is there any way to check whether my carrier is blocking the live stream or not..

Comment: Try the same URI from native browser.. if that does not work then it might me the issue with your carrier as mentioned in the link  I shared.... you might try to updated the youtube app version or try with some other carrier SIM or wifi..

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to the client set to the web view. 
You need to set the user agent as "Chrome" to your web view.

eg. webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Chrome");